# Create a tab view on the fragment

Tags: java, android, fragment, tabview, bottomnavigationview

I created a bottom navigation app, I added 2 buttons. When I click on each buttons it will move to 2  different fragments. I want to add tab view in first fragment  (black fragment). I want 3 tabs in  tab view like WhatsApp. When I slide the tab it must go to the other fragment. I tried, it is not working.

(My project is already working good the bottom navigation view, I want to add tab view in the blankfragment, java code and XML file)

Download project code

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_36gwgzDoNRbGd4R2NlX0RpeU0/view?usp=drivesdk!

[Like this screen shot image model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxxp4.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this example, it will help you achieve what you want:

**The first section is how to implement a `ViewPager` with `BottomNavigation`**

`MainActivity`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;

//This is our viewPager
private ViewPager viewPager;


//Fragments

ChatFragment chatFragment;
CallsFragment callsFragment;
ContactsFragment contactsFragment;
MenuItem prevMenuItem;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Initializing viewPager
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

    //Initializing the bottomNavigationView
    bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView)findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);

    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(
            new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.action_call:
                            viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                            break;
                        case R.id.action_chat:
                            viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
                            break;
                        case R.id.action_contact:
                            viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
                            break;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });

    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            if (prevMenuItem != null) {
                prevMenuItem.setChecked(false);
            }
            else
            {
                bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(false);
            }
            Log.d("page", "onPageSelected: "+position);
            bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(position).setChecked(true);
            prevMenuItem = bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(position);

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });

   /*  //Disable ViewPager Swipe
   viewPager.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
        {
            return true;
        }
    });
    */

    setupViewPager(viewPager);
}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    callsFragment=new CallsFragment();
    chatFragment=new ChatFragment();
    contactsFragment=new ContactsFragment();
    adapter.addFragment(callsFragment);
    adapter.addFragment(chatFragment);
    adapter.addFragment(contactsFragment);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

`ViewPagerAdapter:`

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();

public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
    super(manager);
}
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return mFragmentList.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mFragmentList.size();
}

public void addFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    mFragmentList.add(fragment);
}

}
```

`activity_main.xml`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="droidmentor.bnv_with_viewpager.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_navigation_color_selector"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_navigation_color_selector"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_bottom_navigation" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

### EDIT

**This will show how to put a `ViewPager` inside a `Fragment`:**

Change your `fragment_blank.xml` to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"/>

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Inside your `BlankFragment.java` do this:

```
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                       ViewGroup container,
                       Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View result=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
    ViewPager pager=(ViewPager)result.findViewById(R.id.pager);

    pager.setAdapter(buildAdapter());

    return(result);
  }

  private PagerAdapter buildAdapter() {
    return(new SampleAdapter(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager()));
  }
}
```

Create a `Adapter` I called mine `SampleAdapter`:

```
public class SampleAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
Context ctxt=null;

public SampleAdapter(Context ctxt, FragmentManager mgr) {
    super(mgr);
    this.ctxt=ctxt;
}

  @Override
    public int getCount() {
    return(10);
  }

  @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return(EditorFragment.newInstance(position));
  }

  @Override
    public String getPageTitle(int position) {
    return(EditorFragment.getTitle(ctxt, position));
  }
}
```

---

**MORE OPTIONS:**

**If you want a `TabLayout` inside your fragment:**

```
ViewPager viewPager;
TabLayout tabLayout;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tab);

    return view;
 }

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    setupViewPager(viewPager);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
```

If you choose to do this, then you will have to place the following inside your `fragment_blank`:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_color_selector"        
/>
```

Comment: My project is arledy working good the bootom navigation view , i want to add tab view in the blankfragment , java code and XML file

Comment: Thank for your reply , this is how I wanted  My project is a bottom navigation and tab view project, in this project I have added bottom navigation code this working properly, now I want to add tab view on blank fragment ,

Comment: Tanks sir ,  I hope you can do it

Comment: @Shababkm ok please see my new answer

Comment: Okay for your reply and answer sir ,     you just see my question I add the image (screenshot). https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxxp4.png

Comment: Ok so what do you want more of me? I have shown you how to implement a `viewpager` with `buttomNavigation`? The rest you can do yourself, we are here to help not build the whole app.

Comment: Okay , this is not what I asked for , I have already created bottom navigation is working , I wand create a tab view in a fragment , how can I create tab view in a fragment layout , with java code , this us what I meant

Comment: I am not an android developer I have not studied about this, I studied through internet, you have to help me, the code you said please add to my project code, then please send that link,  I will be witting , hop you will send the code,.

Comment: @Shababkm look on my profile, my email is there, send me a email so we can talk more

Comment: Okay , I will send an email please check your email